# UDP Ipv6 connect fails when choosing default interface for multicast

Tags: c, sockets, udp, ipv6, multicast

### Problem description

I'm currently trying to set up an ipv6 client/server UDP communication with multicast.

#### connect + send

The problem I'm facing occurs during the `connect` call for ipv6 UDP multicast socket:

- **(a)** If I choose the default interface `0` with `setsockopt` and `IPV6_MULTICAST_IF` the connect call will fail.
- **(b)** If I choose an interface index that corresponds to one actual active multicast interface in my system (e.g. `ìf_nametoindex("eth0")`) then it will succeed.

#### sendto

When using `sendto` without a prior `connect` for the destination address it will succeed in both cases with the default interface `0` **(a)** or a corresponding interface via `if_nametoindex` **(b)**.

### Example

The example showcases the four possibilities of running the client to send to a multicast address. Compile and run:

- connect + send (a): `./main 1` - Fails with: Invalid argument
- connect + send (b): `./main 1 eth0` - Succeeds
- sendto (a): `./main 0` - Succeeds
- sendto (b): `./main 0 eth0` - Succeeds

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAXBUF 65536
#define ADDR "ff02::1:5"
#define PORT "50000"

int client(int use_connect_and_send, int interface_index) {
    int sock;
    int status;
    struct addrinfo sainfo, *psinfo, *linfo;
    struct sockaddr_in6 sin6;
    int sin6len;
    char buffer[MAXBUF];
    sprintf(buffer, "hello");

    sin6len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6);

    sock = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

    memset(&sin6, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    sin6.sin6_port = htons(0);
    sin6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    sin6.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;

    memset(&sainfo, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    memset(&sin6, 0, sin6len);

    sainfo.ai_flags = 0;
    sainfo.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    sainfo.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;
    sainfo.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_UDP;
    
    status = getaddrinfo(ADDR, PORT, &sainfo, &psinfo);

    struct ipv6_mreq ipv6;
    ipv6.ipv6mr_interface = interface_index;

    if((setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_MULTICAST_IF, (const void *) &ipv6.ipv6mr_interface, 
                sizeof(ipv6.ipv6mr_interface))) < 0) {
        perror("Setting local interface error");
    }

    if (use_connect_and_send) {
        status = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)psinfo->ai_addr, sin6len);
        if(status != 0) {
           perror("connect failed");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        status = send(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    } else {
        status = sendto(sock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0,
                 (struct sockaddr *)psinfo->ai_addr, sin6len);
    }
    if (status < 0) {
        perror("send failed");
    }
    printf("buffer : %s \t%d\n", buffer, status);

    // free memory
    freeaddrinfo(psinfo);
    psinfo = NULL;

    shutdown(sock, 2);
    close(sock);
    return 0;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if(argc < 2) {
        printf("specify wheter or not to use sendto (0) or connect+send (1)\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    int use_connect_and_send = atoi(argv[1]);
    int interface_index = 0; 
    if(argc > 2) {
        interface_index = if_nametoindex(argv[2]);
        if (interface_index == 0) {
            perror("nametoindex failed, does the given interface exist?");
        }
    }
    client(use_connect_and_send, interface_index);
}
```

### Question

Do you know what I'm doing wrong in the case **connect + send (a)** ? Why does it behave differently from `sendto` which succeeds with the default interface?

Comment: I just had a look into the Linux kernel source: You cannot `connect()` to an IPv6 link-local or multicast address without specifying an interface. I think that the socket is assigned a source address when using `connect()` - and this is only possible if the interface is known.